# Using an event handler with a singleton c#. EventHandler is null

Tags: c#, delegates, singleton

I have a singleton class and an eventHandler sendResponse. 
I want to perform some operation in a subscriber class when the publisher raises
the event.

```
public class Publisher
{
    private static Publisher instance;
    public event EventHandler SendResponse;

    public static Publisher Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Publisher();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void Send()
    {
        this.SendResponse(instance, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In the subscriber, I say

```
public string performSomething()
{
       Publisher copy = Publisher.Instance;
       copy.SendResponse += new EventHandler(copy_SendResponse);
       bool isCompleted = false;

       // Start an async task method which is in another class and is the publisher.

       while(isCompleted != true);
       return "Success";
}

//Define the function copy_SendResponse.
public void copy_SendResponse()
{
      isCompleted = true;
}
```

The code with the subscriber gets executed first.
But SendResponse is not bound to anything when i call the Send() method in the publisher.
In the publisher i am using

```
 // when async task completes
 Publisher copy = Publisher.Instance;
 copy.Send();
 // end of function
```

On debugging, SendResponse is actually null when i say copy.Send(). 
It throws an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: How are you able to call `Send()` if it is `private`?

Comment: yup, sorry. made the change

Comment: it is public in my code

Comment: So what's the problem? What is copy_SendResponse and does it get called?

Comment: I call copy.Send, and I want it to actually invoke copy_sendResponse

Comment: Are multiple threads calling `Publisher.Instance`? Because your current implementation isn't thread-safe.

Comment: @RaviSanker added a working example to my answer. Please check the differences to your code!

Comment: Tip: Wrap `Publisher instance` with `Lazy<T>`. It's thread safe.

Comment: Tip2: Initialize your events with an empty delegate. This will make checking for null and copying the events redundant. Example: `public event EventHandler SendResponse = delegate{};`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, yes multiple threads are calling it.

Comment: Then you have a race condition which is causing multiple objects to be created.

Answer (score 2):

At first i would delcare singleton always like this: `private static Publisher instance = new Publisher();`, in my point of view this is clearer than in the getter. Second, always proof whether your event is subscripted:

```
private void Send()
{
    if (this.SendResponse != null)
    {
        this.SendResponse(this, EventArgs.Empty); // <<-- pass this
    }
}
```

If you want to be sure, that no one else can make an instance of the singleton class, make it's constructor `private`. Rather pass `this` instead of `instance`, to be sure your passing the correct object as sender.

If you follow all rules, your code should work. I can not see any other problem with the amount of your information/code.

**EDIT**

Working example:

```
public class Publisher
{
    // Instance
    private static readonly Publisher instance = new Publisher();
    public event EventHandler SendResponse;

    public static Publisher Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Private constructor
    /// </summary>
    private Publisher()
    {

    }

    public void Send()
    {
        // proof if subscipted
        if (this.SendResponse != null)
        {
            // Pass this
            this.SendResponse(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var copy = Publisher.Instance;
        copy.SendResponse += Copy_SendResponse;

        var copy2 = Publisher.Instance;
        copy2.Send();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private static void Copy_SendResponse(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It works!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input .
I am actually writing an API, which is the subscriber. It spawns an asynctask and starts a timer and continuosly monitors a flag. In the async task class, when it completes, I send the event. 
copy_SendResponse() is used to set the flag to true. When the flag is true, i return the response of the API as a success. But the problem is, in the async task when i say copy.Send(), it doesnt invoke the method. It throws an error. {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: I think you have a problem with your architecture, you should not work like this. I will search for som eother example after work.